# Extrude into geometry at edge of model

Tags: extrude

(Probably not the best title for this issue but I've no idea what to write instead)

I have this model

[image: Before extrude]

And I want to extrude the selected area along Z by -0.1. When I do that I end up with this

[image: After extrude]

As you can see I get a "fence" along the outer edge of the model, which I don't want. I tried ticking "Disolve orthognoal edges", and that is why the fence is missing one face.

I understand why the extrude command does this, but I can't figure out how to do it properly, and preferably fast (since I have to do a lot of these hexes). Deleting the fences' vertices screws up the remaining geometry, so fixing it after the extrude command is not straight forward, at least not for a newbie like me.

Any and all pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: if extrude manifold doesn't work, maybe do the opposite (extrude upwards the other part, then lower down the whole top?)

Comment: Yes that is second possible solution in my mind as well, but it still depends on what exactly he needs, this solution would remove the bad topology, try both and see which one is faster for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Manifold extrude:
[image]

You will find this either by holding Alt+E and selecting manifold, or by changing default extrude to manifold in your tools by holding it:
[image]

Your topology will be still wrong as it will create ngons (technically, but it really depends on if you really need topology to be right or not)

Okay, after reviewing your file, this is the problem:
[image]

This happens for a simple reason, the reason is that your face on that side has 5 vertices and not 4.. that's all, look what happens when I cut it with a knife into 2:
[image]

And it suddenly works when you add a line in the red spot, this is due to you should always make your topology as clean as possible, in your case you need to remove faces with 5 vertices and make 2 with 4 vertices. Always try to go for quads.

Comment: I tried it, but it left a small piece of fence intact. Extruding the higher part up first then moving all the top vertices down again as the other commenter suggested did the trick. Not sure why it worked so well for you in the above picture but not for me

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You guys are super-helpful! https://pasteall.org/blend/d98d2c6a9b55457cb4d2107e1284e9ef

Comment: I just looked at it and I know why it is happening, your topology has 1 mistake, let me show in my answer, I will edit it in a second,... edited

Comment: Thank your for investigating. But you used the knife on the extruded mesh, right? After the fact I mean. Can I avoid the issue altogether by dividing that face before I extrude down?

Comment: Never mind, I had another look at my model I and get what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: No, I used knife on original model, I just didn't include it in photos